# Year returns as 1901

Tags: javascript

I want a user to enter a date in **`mm/dd/yyyy`** format only. After the user enters date and submits the form I validate the date value field as below:

```
function(value, element) {
            var date = new Date(value);
            if (isNaN(date))
                return false;
            var year = date.getFullYear();
            if (year.toString().length != 4)
            return false;
            return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
        }
```

However for testing purpose when I enter date as "**12/12/01**" - I see that full year is coming as **`1901`** which should actually be **`2001`** since it is the current century.

How can I correct check user to entered date in : **`dd/mm/yyyy`** format?

Comment: Why cant you use a calendar so that to avoid all of these checks?

Comment: You test the value *before* you try to convert it to a date object.

Comment: Strange. This should not happen. All years 00 to 15 should return 20##, while 16 to 99 should return 19##?

Comment: Check the value using a regular expressing before converting the value to the date object.

Comment: But yes. Return error when date is not in mm/dd/yyyy format fixes this problem.

Comment: Thanks to all for everyone's suggestion. Checking the format prior to converting it in data object solved the issue

Comment: Do not use the Date constructor to parse strings. For the format you specify it is implementation dependant. Most browsers will treat a two digit year as in the 20th century and add 1900.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two aspects to your question:

1. Is the string the correct format?
2. Does it represent a valid date?

The required format can be tested using a regular expression like:

```
/\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4}/;
```

The date itself can be tested by various means (including a long a complex regular expression, examples of which are here on SO), probably the simplest for this format is to create a Date and test the result. The following function will parse a string in n/n/n format and return either a Date object if it represents a valid date in m/d/y format, or NaN if it doesn't:

```
// Treats 2 digit years as years 0 - 99, not 1900 to 1999
function parseMDY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date();
  d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  d.setFullYear(b[2], --b[0], b[1]);
  return d.getMonth() == b[0]? d : NaN;
}
```

So to validate the date you can use something like:

```
// Return true if s is a valid date in mm/dd/yyyy format
function validateDate(s) {
  return !!(/\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4}/.test(s) && parseMDY(s));
}

console.log(validateDate('30/02/2015')) // false  (invalid date)
console.log(validateDate('02/02/2015')) // true   (valid date)
console.log(validateDate('2/02/2015'))  // false  (incorrect format)
```

This will not detect if the user has accidentally transposed the month and day numbers but still produced a valid date, so that 01/02/20115 may be intended to represent 1 February and not 2 January. It is helpful to reflect the input date in an unambiguous format to help prevent such errors.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution to check that if user entered correct date:

```
function isDate(str) {
  var m = str.match(/^(\d{2})\/(\d[1-12])\/(\d{4})$/);
  return (m) ? true : false;
}
```

Now call it simply with user entered date

```
isDate('03/05/1991') ==> true
```

Comment: `isDate('2/30/2015');` gives `true` when it should return `false`.

Comment: It now returns false for '02/28/2015', which is a valid date (according to the OP format). The function doesn't check if the string actually represents a valid date, only if it has characters that fit a simple pattern.

Comment: @RobG the format that was asked in this question was dd/mm/yyyy. So my function is correct according to that expression.

Comment: @AdnanAhmed—see the OP: "*I want a user to enter a date in mm/dd/yyyy*".